# How could I remove these patio slabs to create a lawn?

Tags: lawn, patio

I'd like to remove the patio slabs and lay some turf or plant lawn seeds on the top level of this mid terraced London garden. My plan also includes removing the brick retaining walls from the permimiter on the top level. This will be to create a more square/Rectangle lawn. I'd like some advice on removing the patio slabs and turfing options for the top level please. Also some ideas for a new retaining wall please, could be anything from sleepers to hold back the soil to a new brick retaining wall or even some new gravel boards for the fencing. Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the photos, what compass direction are you facing? What are you going to do with the lower level of the garden? Where is the lawnmower going to be stored?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm facing west when taking the photo. There's another lower level to the garden where a shed can be built for storage I also have a courtyard to the front with two utility rooms for garden tool storage.

Comment: How many hours of sun do you think that area gets per day?

Comment: The sun is hitting that area from 10 am until about 3pm. My neighbour to the right has a full lawn and grows lettuce.

Comment: Five hours of sun? Wow, that's not a lot for grass. In the northern US, that's fescues and ryegrass, maybe - or sedges. Please let us know what grass you decide to grow - I'm very curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Detail of image from qquestion]

Start here where they appear to be loose, and pull them up, using your hands and/or a prybar as needed, proceeding up and to the right.

If you are removing these and the upper brick retaining walls, given the annoyance of both disposing and sourcing materials in a city garden, I'd strongly consider using these pavers and the bricks you remove as materials for your new retaining wall.

Comment: Great idea regarding using the bricks! Thanks. I thought the same regarding starting in that corner I have a prybar left in the house by the previous owners so I'll start there.